# How to trigger a specific autopilot task when the user text unknown text?

Tags: twilio, twilio-autopilot

How to trigger a specific Autopilot task when the user texts unknown text (keywords that are not included in "Train" of any other Autopilot tasks)?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score -2):

Autopilot should have a fallback task for utterances it doesn’t understand.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api/assistant/defaults